# STemWin STM32F429 Discovery Screen Rotation by 90 degrees

Tags: graphic, screen-rotation, lcd, stm32f4discovery

I'd like to rotate screen of STM32F429 Discovery by 90 degrees. It is OK when size of any axis is less than 240px. However for size is greater than 240px, image on the screen was corrupted. Please refer [this](http://forum.segger.com/index.php?page=Thread&postID=6914#post6914) link. for further information about the issue.

My configuration is as follow

- Hardware: STM32F429 Discovery
- Graphic Library: STemWin 5.22
- Compiler/IDE: GCC/EmBlocks 2.30

Thanks in advance